# How to update row pointer in code visible at left side of DataGridView control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

There is a triangle shaped pointer on the left side of `DataGridView` which indicates currently selected row, I want to shift the pointer to the row just updated.

Comment: Do you want to paint another *pointer* on the Row header or do you want to set the current Row to the one just updated?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Disbacolum", "riteguise?")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(4)
    DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = "wut"
    DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = "awwwwyeee"
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0)
End Sub
```

:) :) :) :)
[image: Here Go]